# Wordpress 'nav_menu_link_attributes' Задать class только первому вложенному элементу <a>

Tags: php, wordpress

Добрый день. Есть следующий код верстки:

```
<nav class="main__menu">
   <ul class="main__menu_basic">
       <li><a href="#">Речные круизы по России</a></li>
           <ul class="main__menu_nested">
                <li><a href="#">Поиск круизов</a></li>
```

C помощью nav_menu_link_attributes добавлю к `<a>` class="main__menu_basic_link main__menu_basic_link_alignment".

Проблема в том, что он добавляется ко всем элементам ,  а мне необходимо, что бы он добавился только к первым элементам  в списке, т.е. должно получиться:

```
<nav class="main__menu">
    <ul class="main__menu_basic">
        <li><a class="main__menu_basic_link main__menu_basic_link_alignment" href="#">Речные круизы по России</a></li>
            <ul class="main__menu_nested">
                <li><a href="#">Поиск круизов</a></li>
```

Я делал следующим образом:

```
wp_nav_menu(array(
    'menu' => 'left menu',
    'menu_class' => 'main__menu_basic',
    'container' => 'nav', 
    'container_class' => 'main__menu',      
    'menu_id' => '',
    'depth' => 3,    
    'theme_location'=>'left'           
));


function add_left_menu_a_class( $atts, $item, $args) {
    // check if the item is in the left menu
    if( $args->theme_location == 'left' ) {
        // add the desired attributes:
        $atts['class'] = 'main__menu_basic_link main__menu_basic_link_alignment';
    }
    return $atts;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_left_menu_a_class', 10, 3);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

С версии WordPress 4.1.0 у функции add_left_menu_a_class появился четвертый параметр - $depth. Указывает уровень меню. Насколько я понимаю, вам нужно изменить классы на нулевом уровне меню. Попробуйте такой код:

```
function add_left_menu_a_class( $atts, $item, $args, $depth) {
    // check if the item is in the left menu
    if ( ( $args->theme_location == 'left' ) && ( $depth == 0 ) ) {
        // add the desired attributes:
        $atts['class'] = 'main__menu_basic_link main__menu_basic_link_alignment';
    }
    return $atts;
}
add_filter('nav_menu_link_attributes', 'add_left_menu_a_class', 10, 4);
```

Comment: Хм странно, добавил раньше пробовал добавлять $depth не помогало. Вы не могли бы пояснить, как это работает

Comment: и пишет в коде  warning, это критично ?                                                          <b>Warning</b>:  Missing argument 4 for add_left_menu_a_class() in <b>D:\sync\Web_data\kurstravel\wp-content\themes\ktravel\functions.php</b> on line <b>47</b><br />
<br />

Comment: в add_filter() `, 4);` указано? Или 3 осталось?

Comment: у меня указано 4 сейчас

Comment: А что в 47 строке и какая версия WP?

Comment: строка 47 это функция function add_left_menu_a_class Версия 4.7.3

Comment: Если написать так: function add_left_menu_a_class( $atts, $item, $args, $depth = 0 ) то варнинги исчезают

Answer (score 0):

Посмотрите и попробуйте воспользоваться псевдоклассом css :first-child

http://htmlbook.ru/css/first-child

Comment: Этот псевдокласс изменит только первый тэг <a> , он никак не повлияет на остальные элементы <a> первого уровня

Answer (score 0):

Капитан на мостике - через админку настроить можно классы:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: кэп протри бинокль, они настраивают классы для ul > li, мне надо для ul>li>a

Comment: Капитан опять приходит на помощь, потому что если настроить нормальный вывод меню, то и классы будут задаваться в нужном месте.

Comment: и где же это там настраиваится ?